# Why does gwibber-service-facebook/twitter updates when I have uninstalled Gwibber?

Tags: gwibber

I uninstalled Gwibber, the social networking tool as soon as I made a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04. However in recent updates (via apt-get update/upgrade commands), gwibber-service-twitter and gwibber-service-facebook have been updated.

1. Why did this happen?
2. Why didn't the Gwibber related packages not removed when Gwibber was uninstalled? Are these components still being used by other software?
3. Is there not a way to remove no-longer-related software components?

Answer (score 1):

If you uninstalled Gwibber using the command line (eg. `sudo apt-get remove gwibber`), or uninstalled Gwibber via the Software Centre, then only the gwibber package may have been removed.  This package contains only the user interface for the Gwibber client. The plugins (eg. gwibber-service-twitter etc) do not depend on it, and so may not have been removed

You also need to remove the gwibber-service package.  This package is responsible for the backend of Gwibber - account details, checking for new messages etc.  The plug-in packages (and the gwibber package) all depend on this.  Removing this package (eg. `sudo apt-get remove gwibber-service`) should prompt you that any plugin packages installed will also be removed.  Using the software centre, search for **gwibber** and click **Show x technical items** at the bottom of the search window.  **gwibber-service** will be listed here and may be uninstalled by clincking the **Uninstall** button.

Comment: I uninstalled gwibber from software center. It should have removed dependencies as well. Otherwise this is a major problem in ubuntu.

Comment: Sorry. Your mention of using "apt-get update/upgrade" led me to assume that you had also uninstalled Gwibber using the command line.  The answer also applies to uninstalling via the software centre.  gwibber-service is listed under the "technical items" when you search for gwibber (along with all the plugins).  I will amend the answer to reflect this.

Comment: I've reported this as a bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/gwibber/+bug/1005522